# why does this cause Segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../library/string.c"

int test(char* left, char* right) {
    while ( *left != '\0') {
        printf("%p\t%d, %d\n", left, (*left) + 1, *left);
        left++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char* a = "hello,kittz";
    char* b = "hello,kitty";
    test(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

when I execute the codes above , here are the output:

```
0x40073f    105, 104
0x400740    102, 101
0x400741    109, 108
0x400742    109, 108
0x400743    112, 111
0x400744    45, 44
0x400745    108, 107
0x400746    106, 105
0x400747    117, 116
0x400748    117, 116
0x400749    123, 122
```

But when i change the code to be :

```
int test(char* left, char* right) {
    while ( *left != '\0') {
        printf("%p\t%d, %d\n", left, (*left)++, *left);
        left++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output tell me that there is something wrong occurs. Here is the output:
Segmentation Fault (core dumped).

Comment: Please format your code before posting it; you'd have greater chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this with debug flags (using `-g`), dropping this into `gdb` and stepping through your code to pinpoint where the segfault is happening?

Comment: i assume those `**` are meant to be a highlight not actual code. Can you take them out and show the actual code you are running

Comment: String literal can not be changed.

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the strings hello,kitt* are stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(*left)++
```

is trying to change the value that `left` points at - ie it is trying to change the compile time literal 'k' to 'l'. This is not allowed (strictly speaking its 'Undefined Behavior' - this means it might work on some systems sometimes, or it might format your hard drive, or light up the xmas tree on the white house lawn...)

Comment: -1 -- that is actually quite fine thing to do in C on general-purpose computers in reasonable compiler. You may have problem if string literals are placed in read-only memory

Comment: Upvoted.  A correct answer. @lowtech Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: if you want strict talk specify what C you are talking about.

Comment: @lowtech ISO 9899 See here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info, this is the tag being used on this question.

Comment: Correct answer, but we also to add that this is an undefined behaviour only in case of global variable, in case of local variable it's accepted isn't ?

Comment: @lowtech. ideone blows up, the OP's compiler blows up. Maybe on your machine ti works. But its clearly undefined behavior

Comment: @fedi String literals have only static storage duration. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: what version of C language you are talking about?

Comment: @lowtech - its UB, you are demostrating that by asking what compiler it is. If it was defined behavior that would be a redundant question. Different modern compilers do different things - proof

Comment: UB for this example is not part of language definition - that is my point. it is only design choice of compiler writer - possibly easily overriden compiler switches. In any case UB is not a reason why seg fault occurs

Comment: @2501, OK, you're right, No Modification for string Literal

Comment: If the string was defined like, char a[12] = {'h','e','l','l','o',',','k','i','t','t','z'}; it will works, but i'am not sure to undrestand why it works

Comment: @fedi That is not a string literal, just as: `char a[]= "hello"` isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

For finding a segfault, you can use many tools.

First compile with the flags `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` could sometime help.

Also, you could use as @Jules says to add the `-g` flag for helping using gdb. and `set env MallocStackLogging 1` in your gdb environment is **REALLY** helpful ! and can show you the line where your segfault occurs

For navigate in a string you can use an Int like :

```
int i = 0;
char str[] = "hello world";

while (str[i])
    putchar(str[i++]);
```

But you can also use pointer like

```
while (*str)
    *str++;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions,  which is so helpful for me since I am freshman to learn C program recently.